# Write message to service bus from HTTP triggered function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to write a function which will received a HTTP POST request, read some data, and write that data to a ServiceBus queue. Here's the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

namespace foo
{
    public static class foo
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(bar))]
        [ServiceBusOutput("myBus", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> bar(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("processed a request.");
            string tld;
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            Models.foo data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.foo>(requestBody);
            theThing = data.Name ?? "";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theThing))
            {
                log.LogError("No data passed to function. Aborting");
                throw new Exception("a message");
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(theThing);
        }
    }
}
```

My local.settings.json contains the following line:

```
"ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "myfunctionnamespace.servicebus.windows.net",
```

I also have this value configured in the Function App application settings and have granted the function data reader and sender privileges via IAM.

I run this in debug from Visual Studio, which gives me a local URL to hit. I can post to this from PostMan, see data getting extracted and the function returns without error. I can also see requests going to the queue, but no messages are written.

I've tried various code changes from different SO posts, none of which have made any difference.

I have the following packages from NuGet installed:

- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus (5.14.1)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus (5.13.4)
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (4.2.0)

My function.json file looks like this, which I think is wrong?

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.2.0",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/foo.dll",
  "entryPoint": "foo.foo.bar"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just returning `return theThing;`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#usage

Comment: I have just tried it, still nothing in the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value is the HTTP response object. It shouldn't be used to return the message. The message should be enqueued using an output binding on `IAsyncCollector`. Here's how it would look like.

```
[FunctionName(nameof(bar))]
public static async Task<IActionResult> bar(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
  [ServiceBus("%OutputQueue%")] IAsyncCollector<ServiceBusMessage> output,
  ILogger log)
{
  log.LogInformation("processed a request.");
  string tld;
  string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
  Models.foo data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.foo>(requestBody); 
  theThing = data.Name ?? "";

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theThing))
  {
    log.LogError("No data passed to function. Aborting");
    throw new Exception("a message");
  }

  // Enqueue the message
  await output.AddAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(theThing);

  // Return HTTP response, not the message
  return new OkResult();
}
```